# Effect-coding interpretation

Tags: anova

For example in one-way anova we have different type of diets: A,B,C,D.
We want to measure the difference between these diets.

Model:
$Y = Xb + u$

We want to run one-way anova to figure out if the difference between type of diets exists. I want to do it by effect-coding.

Question: how do we interpret the X matrix of contrasts? I don't understand why do we have in the last group "-1" and how doe it help us to interpret the result of anova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have two types of diets A and B, and your model is 
$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X +u$

where $X=1$ for diet A and $X = -1 $ for diet B (effect coding). Then the intercept $\beta_0$ is the mean of $E(Y)$ for diet A and B. $\beta_0 = (E(Y|X=1)+E(Y|X=-1))/2$. $\beta_1$ means the half of  the difference of the $E(Y)$ between diet A and B. $\beta_1 = (E(Y|X=1)-E(Y|X=-1))/2$. You can generalize it into 4 types of diet.

Anyway using the different coding methods will result in different meaning of the parameters. But the conclusions (need some manipulation of the parameter) will be the same regardless what coding you use.